# Table setup for Messaging Functionality (email)

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

We've created an application whereby members of the public can search for each other and get in contact (think of it as a dating site) if they so desire, I'm currently in the process of building the Messaging functionality, but I'm curious on how I go about creating the table(s) in the database.

The current flow of the application is as follows:

User1 clicks on User2 to view his/her profile, scrolls down to the bottom of his/hers profile and types some text into a textarea and clicks send at this point I then pass in the data to the database I then send User2 an email saying "you have mail etc".

Taking that into consideration I would of assumed my Email table within SQL Server would look something like this:

Id (PK) (Increments by 1)

ToUserId (FK) // User who they're getting in contact with

FromUserId (FK) // User who sent the message

Content (nvarchar(3000)

Status (int) // read , new , deleted , sent

EmailDate (datetime)

EmailDeleted (datetime)

But the problem with this setup is both user's maybe sending / replying to each other so I would have multiple entries / statuses in one table which may become a nightmare to manage / control (unless I'm over thinking it)

I've spent a good few hours trying to come up with a solution from browsing on the web trying to gain knowledge for building messaging functionality yet it comes back very shy of results. Has anyone been able to build such functionality that wouldn't mind sharing knowledge with me.

Comment: why would that be a nightmare? seems like a legit design to me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is the first time I'm creating this functionality so I'm a bit optimistic in regards to jumping in a creating the table, another issue I see with what I have supplied is If User2 receives the email and then deletes the email, it will be deleted from User2 sent box because its linked.... I just need some fresh eyes on this as I've been looking at it for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break it to two tables, something like this:

```
TblMessage
(
    Message_Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Message_SentDate datetime not null default(getDate()),
    Message_Title varchar(100),
    Message_Content varchar(max),
    Message_SenderId int, -- (fk to users)
    Message_IsDraft bit not null default(0), -- when 1 it's saved as draft.
    Message_IsDeletedFromOutbox bit not null default(0)-- when 1 don't show on sender outbox
)

TblMessageToRecipient
(
   MTR_UserId int, -- (fk to users)
   MTR_Message_Id int, -- (fk to message)
   MTR_ReadDate datetime null, (if null then status is new)
   MTR_DeleteDate datetime null, (if not null then status is deleted)
   PRIMARY KEY (MTR_UserId, MTR_Message_Id)
)
```

This way you can give the recipient an option to "delete forever" a message and just delete the relevant record from `TblMessageToRecipient`.
Also, you can delete the message completely from `tblMessage` if it doesn't have a reference on the `TblMessageToRecipient` and `Message_DeletedFromOutbox = 1`
(this can be done by a scheduled sql agent job to prevent `tblMessages` from getting too big)

### update:

I hope this will answer your question in the comment:

The **recipient** has several possible statuses:

1. **New** - when `MTR_ReadDate is null`.
2. **Read** -when `MTR_ReadDate is not null, and MTR_DeleteDate is null`.
3. **Recycled** - when `MTR_DeleteDate is null`.
4. **Deleted** - when the record is deleted from `TblMessageToRecipient`.

The **sender** have only 3 possible statuses:

1. **Draft**.
   I've added a bit column to the TblMessage called IsDraft. note that drafts should also save recipient information, so it should be saved in both tables, just show it to the sender in the drafts box, and don't show it to the recipient. Note that when the sender discard the draft you should delete the message from both tables.
2. **Sent**.
   Once the message is in both tables, and `IsDraft = 0`, and `IsDeletedFromOutbox  = 0`, it means that the message was sent. in this case, show it to the sender in the sent messages box, and show it to the recipient.
3. **Deleted from outbox**.
   When `IsDeletedFromOutbox = 1` you simply don't show the message to the sender.
   if the message record does not have any references in the `TblMessageToRecipient`, you can delete the record from `TblMessages` since it was deleted by the sender and by all of it's recipients.

**Update 2:**
To summerize our conversation in the comments, there are 2 mahor ways to keep a conversation structure (meaning the link between a message and a reply to it [and it's reply and so on...])

One way is to keep a `Message_ParentId` nullable column in `TblMessages`.
This column will contain null for any message that is not a reply to an older message, but for replies it will contain the message id of the message it was a reply to.

The second way is to keep a `Message_ConversationId` column that will always contain a value. when a message is a reply to an older message, it's `Message_ConversationId` should be the same as it's parent message. When it's not a reply, it's ConversationId should be generated. Since we are talking about sql server 2008, it means the easiest way to generate a new conversation id every time will be to add a new table called `TblConversation`. this table can keep a single column `Conversation_Id` that will be an int identity column, and to get a new conversation id do something like this:

```
DECLARE @ConversationId int
INSERT INTO TblConversation DEFAULT VALUES
SELECT @ConversationId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and then user the `@ConversationId` when inserting a new root message.

Comment: apologies on not coming back sooner, I've was dragged on to another project, I'm looking at what you've provided but how / where does it separate the different statuses for both users i.e User1 sends the email so that would have a status of 1 for example and it would appear in his Sent box, User2 reads it and then deletes it so it would have a status of 2 and would appear in her delete box ? this is what I'm getting confused about..

Comment: thanks for providing an update, sadly I'm still confused, I'm building a very basic messaging program, so I wont have the drafts, recycled or title I'm trying to get a better grasp on this can you tell me if I have the correct thought.  I contact someone through the site, It inserts a record into the TblMessage table, outputs the insertedId (Message_Id) I then take this Message_Id and insert a record into TblMessageToRecipient UserId being the person I want to contact?

Comment: Just on the back on my comment few minutes ago, this table will potentially grow to a incredible size, what would you recommend for helping with performance i.e looks ups etc I know we have the PK and FK is there anything else I could take into consideration?

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"... don't worry too much about performance now, write readable code and don't be cheep with comments, so that you can understand it when you read it 2 years from now.  Keep in mind that you can always add indexing to the tables.

Comment: Ok thanks, in regards to what I said I.e outputting the inserted I'd etc is that the correct flow?

Comment: yes. it should be done in a single stored procedure.

Comment: And when the recipient responds he/she will follow the same process I.e insert into message table output insertedid and insert into recipient table?

Comment: exactly. if you want to keep a conversation structure you can add a parent id to the messages table, that will be a nullable self foreign key to the message id.

Comment: Interesting, I think that would be more beneficial for me that way I can just pass that in and return all correspondents that's linked by that parentId, when you say nullable why would it be billable? Because I'll be inserting a record which would generate the parentId ? Or have I missed something?

Comment: the first message in the conversation is the root message and it's parent id is null. the following message (the reply) has the parent id that is the id of the first message, and it's reply has the parent id that is it's message id, and so on. then you can retrieve all messages that belongs to the conversation in the correct order. another option is to add a column called conversation id that will have the same value for all messages in the conversation, that will make the select easier but you will need another table to keep the conversation id

Comment: Ok cool, when it comes to populating that ParentId how would I make it unique? because I already have a link by the two tables which is the MessageId which is the PK on the root table, and FK on the Recipient Table I know this MessageId will increment by 1 every time a new message is inserted, but I'm just trying to grasp this a bit better.